# ES6 implementation of this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, ecmascript-6

This function loops through an array of objects, and takes an object as a second parameter.

It will loop through the array of objects replacing it with the object passed in as the second argument if the `firstname` value matches.

I am sure there is a better way of implementing this function using ES6 spread operator but I'm having trouble implementing it.

```js
const foo = (arr, obj) => {
  const tempArray = arr.map((item, i) => {
    if ( arr[i].name === obj.name ) {
      return obj
    } else {
      return arr[i]
    }
  })
  return tempArray
}

const arrOfObjx = [ 
  {
      "name": "Joe",
      "favMovie": "Rambo"
  },
  {
      "name": "Jane",
      "favMovie": "The Matrix"
  },
  {
      "name": "John",
      "favMovie": "Star Wars"
  } 
]

const newJoe = {
  "name": "Joe",
  "favMovie": "ROCKY"
}

console.log(foo(arrOfObjx, newJoe ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no use case for the spread operator here. The simplifications to make are in dropping the `tempArray` variable and in using `item` instead of `arr[i]`:

```
function foo(arr, obj) {
  return arr.map((item, i) => {
    if ( item.name === obj.name ) {
      return obj
    } else {
      return item
    }
  });
}
```

which you can further shorten to

```
const foo = (arr, obj) =>
  arr.map(item =>
    item.name === obj.name ? obj : item
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out using item

```
const tempArray = arr.map((item, i) => {
   if (item.name === obj.name) {
      return obj
   } else {
      return item
   }
})
```

I think you can even write it as

```
const tempArray = arr.map((item, i) => {
   return (item.name === obj.name ? obj : item)
})
```